# There was no endpoint listening at ".svc" that could accept the message

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I get an exception when connecting to a WCF web service.

I add this web service as **Service Reference** in my project.

The address is `http://192.168.16.91:8092/ws_merchants.svc` and wsdl address `http://192.168.16.91:8092/ws_merchants.svc?wsdl`.

In the `app.config`, I have this binding config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Iws_Merchants" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding" 
            address="http://192.168.16.91:8092/ws_merchants.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding"  
            bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Iws_Merchants"
            contract="ServiceReferenceSahand.Iws_merchants" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

My code to use this service :

```
private bool GetToken()
{
    try
    {
        Iws_merchantsClient def = new Iws_merchantsClient();
        var res = def.get_Token("user", "pass");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I get this exception :

> There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.16.91:8092/ws_merchants.svc that could accept the message.
>   This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
>   See InnerException, if present, for more details.

and in the inner exception :

> The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

What is not found, when I add this methods from wsdl as service reference?

Comment: Did you make sure the service is up and running and accessible from the client (use ping to verify for example)? What happen if you open http://192.168.16.91:8092/ws_merchants.svc?wsdl in a browser?

Comment: yes. the service is up and i can see svc and wsdl.

Comment: Is the binding on the **server side** identical to what you're using here on your client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess something is wrong with your wsdl file. you can check your client config file and see if the endpoint address is right or not.
its little tricky. and can cause by so many reasons. i suggest to you start tracing the problem with wcf test client. let me know if you can find anything.

Comment: do you guess this error cause from server side ( 192.168.16.91 )? or from the client that use that service?

Comment: i cant tell you by sure. but i guess its client side error. something might be wrong at your config file. like endpoint address.

Comment: Thank you.
when I add the service reference, nothing added in app.config as binding, and myself write the binding there.
do you think is from client yet?

Comment: have you try to consume the service with wcf test client? do you have a firewall or something like this in the network? i had a slimier problem when i had a firewall on my network and use the route table in order to connect the server.

Comment: connection between client and server is point to point and just 8092 and 80 ports are open.

Comment: when i use wcf test client. i cant add service. there is no error, and said "Service added successfully" , but there is nothing to show in the window.